# Parsing a json array in a json file into a java ArrayList

Tags: java, json, gson, android

I have this Json file:

1. **States.json**

   ```
    [
     {
       "cod": "Z100",
       "name": "ALBANIA",
       "statoSovrano": "",
       "Continent": "EUROPA"
     },
     {
       "cod": "Z101",
       "name": "ANDORRA",
       "statoSovrano": "",
       "Continent": "EUROPA"
     },
     {
       "cod": "Z102",
       "name": "AUSTRIA",
       "statoSovrano": "",
       "Continent": "EUROPA"
     },
     {
       "cod": "Z103",
       "name": "BELGIO",
       "statoSovrano": "",
       "Continent": "EUROPA"
     }    
   ]
   ```

I want to parse  using gson, the json array above into a java ArrayList in order to do other stuff after.
So I created this class:

**2. Country.java**

```
public class Country extends ArrayList<Country>{
  private String name;
  private String cod;
  private String Continent;
  private String statoSovrano;

  Country(String c, String n,String s, String i) {
    name = n;
    cod = c;
    Continent = i;
    statoSovrano =s;
  }


  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getIso() {
    return cod;
  }

  public String getContinent() {
    return Continent;
  }

  public String getStatoSovrano() {
    return statoSovrano;
  }
}
```

But with this method :

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream ims = assetManager.open("states.json");
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(ims);
            Gson gson1=new GsonBuilder().create();

            Type listType =new TypeToken<ArrayList<Country>>()  {   }.getType();
            ArrayList<Country> countries = gson1.fromJson(reader,listType);
```

the last line raises the error:

---

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 2 column 4 path $[0]
```

---

My file json is not an object, why I got this error?

Comment: The json content should start with `[` since it's array.

Comment: Did you make a copy-paste error with `States.json` or is what you show here exactly what you have in the file?

Comment: Another SO member edited your question to show the correct format for States.json. Be sure that your file is the same as the edit.

Comment: Use List, not ArrayList. And a Country is not an ArrayList, so it has no reason to extend ArrayList. Also, remove the constructor, or add a no-arg constructor. Finally, respect the Java naming conventions, and use https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#json-field-naming-support to specify the JSON property names.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it was a copy-paste error. Now modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Country definition - you extend ArrayList for some reason here:

> public class Country **extends ArrayList** {

The bold part makes Gson think your Country is some kind of a list, that's why it expects BEGIN_ARRAY

Change the class signature just to be

```
public class Country {
```

and your code will work

Comment: I don't know why and when I extended the class Country… Ty